# Multiple select query in same Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I got a problem when I want to show my data in view from same table, but I just need one of field in that table.. 
through controller, there were function `index()` and `setID()`

This is my controller

```
public function index(){
    $wo = DB::select('select max(nowo)+1 as nowo, CURRENT_DATE as tgl from workorder');
    return view('entri_wo')->with(['workorder'=>$wo]);
}

public function setID()
{
    $wo = DB::select('select idmontir from workorder');
    return view('entri_wo',['wo'=>$wo]);
}
```

This is my view

[image: entri_workorder]

Also, I want to show this

[image: entri_workorder]

And this is my route

```
Route::get('/entri_wo', 'WoController@index')->name('entri_wo');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller:

```
public function index(){
  $wo = DB::select('select idmontir from workorder');
  $wo2 = DB::select('select max(nowo)+1 as nowo, CURRENT_DATE as tgl from workorder');
  return view('entri_wo',['wo'=>$wo,'workorder'=>$wo2]);
}
```

and in your view:

```
@foreach($wo as $item)
  <option value="{{ $item->idmontir }}" >{{ $item->idmontir }}</option>
@endforeach
```

and :

```
@foreach($workorder as $item)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $item->nowo }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->tgl }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're the best bro.. Thanks for the answer.. it works for me! Great!